# Use regular expressions to detect range of alphanumeric string

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I need help with regular expressions to do the following. I have a list of study subjects, named such as:

```
subject <- c('x-010', 'x-011', 'x-012', 'x-013', 'x-014', 'x-015', 'x-016', 'x-017', 'x-018', 'x-019', 'x-020', 'x-021', 'x-022', 'x-023', 'x-024', 'x-025', 'x-026', 'x-027', 'x-028', 'x-029', 'x-030')

df <- data.frame(subject)
```

I want to add a column to classify the subjects by group according to their number, such that 1 - 10 are in Group A, 11 - 20 are in Group B, 21 - 30 are in Group C, and so on. I don't know how to do this using regular expressions, only to start with:

```
df <- data.frame(subject) %>% 
mutate(case_when(group = str_detect(subject,
```

but need to understand how to describe this pattern.

Comment: This sounds like a job to do in a replacement function, that discerns the number using a formula that gets whole number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can extract the numeric part and create the group with `%/%`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(grp = paste0("Group ", LETTERS[(as.numeric(str_extract(subject, 
                        "[0-9]+"))-1) %/% 10 + 1]))
# A tibble: 21 x 2
# Groups:   grp [3]
#   subject grp    
#   <fct>   <chr>  
# 1 x-010   Group A
# 2 x-011   Group B
# 3 x-012   Group B
# 4 x-013   Group B
# 5 x-014   Group B
# 6 x-015   Group B
# 7 x-016   Group B
# 8 x-017   Group B
# 9 x-018   Group B
#10 x-019   Group B
# ... with 11 more rows
```

Comment: This works for this example. However, I realized that in my actual data, the subject prefixes are a combination of letters and numbers, so, for instance "xyz01-" and then the subject number. So, I can't just extract the number. How can I adapt this code to extract not just all numbers but either: the digits after the "-" or the last 3 digits?

Comment: @user42485 `as.numeric(gsub( "^.+-", "", df$subject))`

Comment: @akrun didn't realize it didn't exactly reproduce every facet